How can I put more than one row in this csv code
import csv

name = input("name: ")
Number1 = input("number1: ")
Number2 = input("number2: ")
local = input("local: ")
continue = input("continue? Y/N: ")
while(continue == ""):
    Name = input("nome: ")
    number1 = input("Inscrição: ")
    Number2 = input("Seção: ")
    local = input("local: ")
    continue = input("continuar? S/N: ")
    v =  open("valores", "w")
    writer = csv.writer(v)
    writer.writerow([Name, number1, number2, local])
    
else:
    print("ok")

I'm trying to get the variables to be written in sequence in a csv file but when I run it it only writes one line, and keeps deleting and rewriting it (I want it to be in a loop until "continuar" == N
like
Name: asdjhagsdjh
number1: kasjhdkhasdkl
Number2: sajfdksdh
local: asjfkjfhsdkj
continue? Y/N: Y
      (asdjhagsdjh,kasjhdkhasdkl,sajfdksdh,asjfkjfhsdkj)
Name: asdjhagsdjh
Number1: kasjhdkhasdkl
Number2: sajfdksdh
local: asjfkjfhsdkj
continue? Y/N: N
      (asdjhagsdjh,kasjhdkhasdkl,sajfdksdh,asjfkjfhsdkj
       asdjhagsdjh,kasjhdkhasdkl,sajfdksdh,asjfkjfhsdkj)

I'm starting now so if it's something stupid: I'm sorry

v =  open("valores", "w") Opening the file in "w" mode erases the existing file contents.  I think you want "a" mode instead.

But it would be even better to rearrange your code so that you only need to open the file once.

"ignore if it's in Portuguese." - We would prefer if you translated it. It's not strictly required, but it does help us understand what the code does. For me personally, I'm not going to write an answer unless it's translated.

Writing ('w') erases the existing file each time it is opened.  If you don't want that, use 'a' (append).  You may want to add code to clear the file if it already exists, but I will leave that as an exercise:
import csv

# Open the file once, all writes will be to the end of the file.
# 'with' will close the file when its block exits.
with open('values.csv', 'a') as v:
    writer = csv.writer(v)
    continue_ = 'y'  # to enter the while loop, assume y for first pass
    while continue_.lower().startswith('y'):  # handles Y, Yes, YES, yes, y, yeppers, etc.
        name = input('Name: ')
        registration = input('Registration: ')
        section = input('Section: ')
        location = input('Location: ')
        writer.writerow([name, registration, section, location])
        continue_ = input('Continue? Y/N: ')  # NOW ask to continue
    else:
        print('ok')

